# Обработка исключений в методе __enter__ менеджера контекста

Tags: python, менеджер-контекста

Есть задача - открыть json, прочитать его, закрыть, содержимое обработать и удалить файл. Во время обработки могут возникнуть исключения. Написал простой менеджер контекста:

```
class open_json:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self):
        print('start enter')
        temp_file = open(self.file_path, 'r')
        return json.load(temp_file)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('start exit')
        os.unlink(self.file_path)

with open_json(r'<path to>.json') as res:
    tree = [res]
```

Однако на этапе тестирования, когда я подсовываю json с заведомо недесериализуемым содержимым, то в `__enter__` возникает ошибка и `__exit__` не выполняется. Не могу понять почему. А мне в любом случае надо удалить файл, и, если возникла ошибка, то вывести ее как `Exception`

Comment: Может, потому, что у вас нет обработки исключений `try ... except`?

Comment: @АлексейР я думал обработка там под капотом менеджера производится. ПРосто если я сам буду проводить обработку то зачем мне тогда __exit__?

Comment: @АлексейР далее в коде. Это просто with open_json(<path to json>)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопросе воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @АлексейР привел вызов

Comment: Тут много полезного написано https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483359/handling-exceptions-inside-context-managers Если вы хотите попасть в `exit`, вам придётся ловить исключение. В общем случае ну сами подумайте - что и зачем будет закрывать/удалять `exit`, если, например, такой файл вообще не существует и при его открытии в `enter` выпадет эксепшен? Скорее вам тут вообще нужно применить конструкцию `try`/`finally`, а не контекстный менеджер. И только на чтение `json`-а, открытия файла оно не должно касаться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обработка ошибки внутри самого метода `__enter__` сама по себе не происходит:

```
class open_json:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self):
        print('start enter')
        raise RuntimeError("test")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('start exit')


with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
    pass
```

Вывод:

```
start enter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 7, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("test")
RuntimeError: test
```

Вывода "start exit" нет, значит `__exit__` не сработал.

Хотя при вылете ошибки внутри блока `with` метод `__exit__` срабатывает:

```
class manager:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self):
        print('start enter')
        # raise RuntimeError("test")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('start exit')


with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
    raise RuntimeError("test")
```

Вывод:

```
start enter
start exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("test")
RuntimeError: test
```

Поэтому внутри `__enter__` ошибку нужно обработать вручную: обернуть код в `try-except`, в `except` вызвать метод `__exit__`, потом пробросить ошибку наружу:

```
class manager:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self):
        print('start enter')
        try:
            raise RuntimeError("test")
        except Exception as ex:
            self.__exit__(type(ex), ex, ex.__traceback__)
            raise ex

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('start exit')


with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
    pass
```

Вывод:

```
start enter
start exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 11, in __enter__
    raise ex
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 8, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("test")
RuntimeError: test
```

---

Удобнее реализовывать контекстные менеджеры через функции с декоратором [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Внутри функции весь код, который потенциально может вызвать ошибку (в том числе и передача данных наружу), нужно обернуть в `try-finally`. В `finally` нужно добавить тот код, который у вас должен выполняться при выходе из блока `with`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def manager(file_path):
    try:
        print('start enter')
        raise RuntimeError("test")
        yield
    finally:
        print('start exit')


with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
    pass
```

Вывод:

```
start enter
start exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    with manager(r'<path to>.json') as res:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 281, in helper
    return _GeneratorContextManager(func, args, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.gen = func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/Projects/test.py", line 8, in manager
    raise RuntimeError("test")
RuntimeError: test
```

При возникновении ошибки сначала будет выполняться блок `finally`, потом уже ошибка ошибка пробросится наружу, т.к. у нас `except` нет. Дальше уже снаружи блока `with` можно будет добавить обработку ошибки, но в данном случае главное, что несмотря на ошибку финальные действия у нас выполнились.

На вашем примере будет что-то такое:

```
import json
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def manager(file_path):
    try:
        print('start enter')
        with open(file_path, 'r') as temp_file:
            yield json.load(temp_file)
    finally:
        print('start exit')
        os.unlink(file_path)
```

Comment: очень круто, спасибо большое, все понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее тут подошло бы что-то такое:

```py
def open_json(file_path):
    temp_file = open(file_path)
    try:
        return json.load(temp_file)
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        temp_file.close()
        os.unlink(file_path)

res = open_json(r'<path to>.json')
tree = [res]
```

Тут основной вопрос в том, что вы хотите делать в двух случаях:

- когда падает эксепшен при открытии файла
- когда падает эксепшен при чтении `json`

В приведённом мной вариаенте эксепшен на битом `json` будет игнорирован, а вот проблема с открытием файла будет эскалирована. Но возможны и другие варианты обработки. Вам главное определиться какое вы хотите поведение метода/класса.

Если вы знаете конкретное исключение, которое хотите игнорировать, то можно сделать чуть более красиво:

```py
def open_json(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path) temp_file:
            return json.load(temp_file)
    except ИсключениеJsonКотороеНужноИгнорить:
        pass
    finally:
        os.unlink(file_path)
```

P.S. Хотя нет, в этом случае опять же нужно будет что-то делать со случаями, когда к файлу нет доступа и т.д., тут лишний раз будет ещё `unlink` вызываться. Нужно будет все конкретные исключения продумывать и обрабатывать по-разному.